Which US State has the most General Aviation aircraft manufacturers?
Curious if there is a specific geolocation manufacturers prefer for building their aircraft knowing that it is a multifactor decision (testing, permits, cost, labor, weather, etc)
I wonder if there is a US State that has the most General Aviation aircraft manufacturers?

It's hard to compare "most." Textron has a huge operation in Wichita but it's one company, while Epic is a building in an airstrip in Oregon.

@user71659 I see your point, I'm just interested knowing by total number of manufacturer companies, doesn't matter if is small or big. The essence of the question is to find out if there is something that attracts manufacturers more to a specific state or it is just spread/random.

It is historical.  Wichita was the home to Beech, Cessna, Stearman, Travel Air, and Learjet.  Boeing followed with a large presence.  Those companies have closed, merged, been bought, etc. leaving mostly Textron (Cessna and Hawker Beechcraft) and Spirit (a Boeing spinoff that is being re-acquired by Boeing).  The other big location for many companies is Los Angeles -- Douglas, Northrop, Lockheed, Hughes, North American (briefly in MD) were all LA centered.

Today, Lockheed employs people in every congressional district.  McDonnell (St. Louis) merged with Douglas, which merged with Boeing.  North American Aviation became Rockwell and is now part of Boeing.  The year-round good flying weather is a good reason for aerospace companies to locate in Southern California.

@RobMcDonald The question asks for GA. Boeing, Lockheed, Spirit aren't GA by any stretch. Those have work-share considerations, GA doesn't.

There is no reason to expect it would be spread at random but it's not to say that there is some objective pre-existing characteristics that attracts manufacturers to a state. It's a common thing for many industries, there is quite a bit of literature (which I do not know very well) on that in economics or policy circles, see Wikipedia.

Don't know the answer but I'll bet Florida's in the top 5.
